# Android Room Database like query not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have added a field to know whether the item is deleted or not by the user and if it is deleted it should not be visible to the user.

I wrote the following query for it

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM post_info WHERE deleted=0 & postedBy LIKE :search || '%' OR  postName LIKE :search || '%' OR postDes LIKE :search || '%' ORDER BY postid DESC ")
     fun searchFilter(search:String):Flow<List<PostEntity>>
```

But i am getting all the data and not only WHERE deleted=0 means false but when I search and filter it manually it works fine like

```
  viewModel.searchFilter(searchQuery).observe(this) {

            it.let {
                var listOF= mutableListOf<PostEntity>()
                for(list in it){
                    if(!list.deleted){
                        listOF.add(list)

                    }
                }
                adapter.setDataList(listOF)}
        }
```

This works fine but the Query doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like query will work with this syntax:

> inputValue LIKE '%' || :fieldToMatch || '%'

`&` should be replaced with `AND`

Replace this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM post_info WHERE deleted=0 & postedBy LIKE :search || '%' OR  postName LIKE :search || '%' OR postDes LIKE :search || '%' ORDER BY postid DESC ")
fun searchFilter(search:String):Flow<List<PostEntity>>
```

With this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM post_info WHERE deleted=0 AND (postedBy LIKE '%' || :search || '%' OR  postName LIKE '%' || :search || '%' OR postDes LIKE '%' || :search || '%') ORDER BY postid DESC ")
fun searchFilter(search:String): Flow<List<PostEntity>>
```

Comment: This doesn't work I am still getting the data that is deleted(means deleted=1), Previously it was `AND` only instead of `&`.

Comment: But as per the accepted answer it worked only when you change it to `AND`

Comment: No bro, parentheses was also required which you didn't add but now you edited so your answer is also accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `&` to `AND` and add parentheses to separate the `OR`s:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM post_info WHERE deleted=0 AND (postedBy LIKE :search || '%' OR  postName LIKE :search || '%' OR postDes LIKE :search || '%') ORDER BY postid DESC ")
fun searchFilter(search:String):Flow<List<PostEntity>>
```